# Trying to login using HttpPost, but it returns with the initial page?

Tags: android, http-post, httpclient

I am trying to login to this page: https://eas.admin.uillinois.edu/eas/servlet/EasLogin?redirect=https://webprod.admin.uillinois.edu/ssa/servlet/SelfServiceLogin?appName=edu.uillinois.aits.SelfServiceLogin&dad=BANPROD1

Using HttpPost on Android.  I looked online and tried httpclient and executed httppost.  However the response is the same URL.  Here is my code, what do I need?  Thanks.

```
     @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_check_balance);
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 

    String username = getIntent().getExtras().getString("username");
    String password = getIntent().getExtras().getString("password");

    //Building post parameters, key and value pair
    List<NameValuePair> accountInfo = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    accountInfo.add(new BasicNameValuePair("inputEnterpriseId", username));
    accountInfo.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));


    //Creating HTTP client
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    //Creating HTTP Post
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(LOGIN_URL);

    /* Not needed?
    BasicHttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
    params.setParameter("ENT_ID", username);
    params.setParameter("PASSWORD", password);
    httpPost.setParams(params);
    */

    //Url Encoding the POST parameters   
    try {
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(accountInfo));
    }
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // writing error to Log
        e.printStackTrace();
        startActivity(new Intent(this, InputAccountActivity.class));
    }

    HttpResponse response = null;
    InputStreamReader iSR = null;
    String source = null;


 // Making HTTP Request
    try {
        response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        source = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent()).toString(); //gets website source

        // writing response to log
        Log.d("Http Response:", response.toString());
        Log.d("hi", source);
        /*
        iSR = new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent());

        HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
        if (resEntity != null) {    
            Log.d("RESPONSE",resEntity.toString());
        }

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(iSR);   
        source = "";

        while((source = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            source += br.readLine();
            Log.d(TAG,source.trim());
        }
        */

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // writing exception to log
        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // writing exception to log
        e.printStackTrace();
        startActivity(new Intent(this, InputAccountActivity.class));
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am just guessing, try changing

```
accountInfo.add(new BasicNameValuePair("inputEnterpriseID", username));
```

to below given code.

```
accountInfo.add(new BasicNameValuePair("inputEnterpriseId", username));
```

I think your Id is incorrect.Hope this will help

Comment: Edited it, nothing changed.